# Cassandra performance for Counter writes

Tags: cassandra

Why can there be a significant difference between "Write Request latency"(4-5ms) and "Local Write latency"(Column Family wise)(.05ms) in as Datastax Opscenter reports
http://www.datastax.com/docs/opscenter/online_help/performance/cluster_metrics#write-request-latency
http://www.datastax.com/docs/opscenter/online_help/performance/cf_metrics#cf-local-write-latency

The above figures are for Counter Column Types written with Consistency level one, so the read done for write for counters shouldn't be a part of the latency.

Comment: Also as Netflix reports 
"The response time measured at the client was about 11ms, with about 1.2ms due to network latency and the rest from the Thrift client library overhead and scheduling delays as the threads pick up responses. The write latency measured at each Cassandra server is a small fraction of a millisecond"
http://techblog.netflix.com/2011/11/benchmarking-cassandra-scalability-on.html

IS this much latency expected only due to thrift and scheduling latency

Answer (score 4):

"Write Request latency"

This metric is tracking latency from the perspective a coordinator node. So this is tracking the latency from when a coordinator node receives a request, forwards it to the correct replicas, and then waits for the appropriate number of responses depending on your consistency level.

"Local Write latency"

This metric is tracking latency from the perspective of a replica. It is only tracking the time from when a replica receives the write from a coordinator until it writes it to the commitlog and memtable and returns.

As you can see the difference is easily explained by the overhead of thrift, network latency, and the consistency level that are all included in the latency reported by the coordinator.